# Cloud composer airflow worker pod connect to cloud sql

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

is it is possible to modify airflow worker pod deployment ? I have to add one side car container to. Connect to. Our custom cloud sql using private IP with cloud sql. Proxy.? What if nodes evict??? That time my deployment won't get erased??

We have problem of kubernetes node eviction.. So my sidecar should run in my new node as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the simpler way is to follow [1].

If you don't want to use the Cloud SQL Proxy, you can take a look at [2], where both methods (with/without Proxy) are explained.

You can avoid node eviction issues by increasing the size of the Composer environment, either by adding a node pool to the GKE cluster, or by increasing the environment's size using gcloud:

```
gcloud composer environments update ${COMPOSER_ENV_NAME} \
    --location=$ZONE \
    --node-count=$TARGET_NUM_NODES
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#configuring_a_connection_to_an_external_database

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine